# mysqlclient install error - ld: library not found for -lzlib

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, python-install

I'm trying to install `mysqlclient` on MacOS from requirements.txt of a Python(3.8) project. I created a virtual environment and this is the output while trying to install it:

```
ld: library not found for -lzlib  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1  
[end of output]
```

Note that `lzlib` is already installed. I read that MacOS has `clang` for compilation of C libraries and I installed `gcc` using Homebrew. Still the default `clang` was being picked up as is evident from the following output:

```
$ gcc -v  
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)  
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.4.0  
Thread model: posix  
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin 



$ gcc-13 -v  
Using built-in specs.  
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-13  
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin22/13/lto-wrapper  
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22  
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/opt/gcc --libdir=/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-13 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-zstd=/usr/local/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 13.1.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --with-system-zlib --build=x86_64-apple-darwin22 --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk  
Thread model: posix  
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd  
gcc version 13.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0)
```

So, I tried to set the alias for gcc in my `.zshrc` which showed correct output in terminal but the command to install `mysqlclient` still fails with same error message. I tried to install multiple packages as suggested in different answers but still the error is same.

Answer (score 2):

Run `brew info zlib` to get the path to your zlib.

Likely: `"-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"`

Open your mysql config file in any editor, example:

`> sudo vim /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin/mysql_config`

In this file you'll find the libraries. I updated `zlib` to be the direct library

before:

```
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lzlib  -lzstd -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lresolv"
```

After

```
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib  -lzstd -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lresolv"
```

Don't know if it's the most elegant solution but this workaround got me to install mysql_client

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to the `linker` not being able to find the necessary libraries during the installation of `mysqlclient`.

Ensure that you have the `zlib` library installed. You mentioned that it's already installed, but double-check to make sure it's available in the default library search path. You can use the brew command to install it if needed:

```
brew install zlib
```

Set the `LDFLAGS` environment variable to include the `zlib` library path before installing `mysqlclient`. Open a new terminal window and run the following command:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
```

Run the installation of `mysqlclient` again using pip within your virtual environment:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If the above steps don't work, you can try explicitly specifying the location of the `zlib` library during the installation:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
```

By setting the `LDFLAGS` environment variable or providing the library location explicitly, you're telling the linker where to find the `zlib` library, which is needed by `mysqlclient`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in homebrew with https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/131207